# parallel FFT resources on FPGA

Tags: fft

Given my FPGA working frequency and the input data throughput to it I need to parallelise my FFT algorithm. For instance:

input throughput = 40 Gsps
fclock = 400 MHz
Parallelization = 40 Gsps/400 MHz = 100 -> or 128

Now in case I want to perform an FFT with 1024 points, I guess I could look for a radix-2 algorithm with a level of parallelization 128 for instance and estimate the corresponding resources. However, if I want to do an FFT of 64 points, how affects my resources the fact that the parallelization is larger than my number of FFT points? Does it mean that a 128 parallel 64-point FFT will require the same resources than a 128 parallel 128-point FFT in which only some algorithm re-routing has been done to accommodate the 64 points? Or effectively I could still reduce the resources when doing 64-point FFT even if my input requires more parallel streams?

Comment: Remember that the complexity of the FFT is N * log(N), not N. So 1, 128-point FFT will be more complex than two 64-point FFT. Also a 128-point FFT may require higher precision than a 64-point FFT. Other ways to optimize is to implement a split radix-4 FFT.

Comment: One of the issues here is that I have seen some work in literature that analyzes the resources of different N-point FFT using radix-2, for different levels of parallelization P. But the level of parallelization is always lower than the number of FFT points (P<N), meaning that you cannot parallelize more than the number of FFT points. However, if you really need a certain P and a lower N, I'm not sure what happens to resources when P>N.

Comment: Then you just implement multiple instances of the FFT in parallel and work with some routing logic so that when the data arrives it is sent to one of the FFT blocks.